# Solving a "expression must have pointer to class type" error

Tags: c++, pointers, operator-precedence

```
class testClass { public: int B, C; };

testClass u;
testClass * k = &u;
testClass ** m = &k;

*m->B = 1;//Error appears here
```

I think I've followed the rules of pointer referencing correctly. I still have no idea why this is happening. Could someone help me?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`operator->` has higher [precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) than `operator*`, so `*m->B` is equivalent as `*(m->B)`; while `m->B` is not valid here.

You should change it to `(*m)->B`.

Comment: Epic thanks! I'll mark this as the answer as soon as it allows me to! ( 11 minutes, apparently)